# Problems placing delay() in repetitive jQuery animation

Tags: jquery

I've created a jQuery function that animates elements from top 50px to top 150px, one after the other, repetitively.

I am trying to create a pause between the animation of each individual element (not a pause between the iterations). At the first iteration, nothing happens. In the following ones, the function considers the delay(), but only to a part of the elements.

You can see the whole thing in action in the link below.

[THE ENTIRE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/HdpPj/)

```
    $(".but").click(function() {
        function repeat() {
            var count = $(".box").length;
            $($(".box").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay(600 * i).animate({
                    top: "150px",
                    duration: 600,
                    easing: "linear",
                    complete: function() {
                        $(".box").each(function(i) {
                            $(this).delay(500);
                        });
                        if (count == 0) {
                            $(".box").css("top", "50px");
                            repeat();
                        };
                    }
                });
            });
        };
        repeat();
    });
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: your jsfiddle code calls `repeat()` inside the click event function

Comment: Why is the dealy function only works after the second iteration? and even then, why does it only work for some of the elements?

Comment: I tried placing the repeat() in and out of the click, or both in and out, with no success.

Comment: @Sahar Soffer There is error in your coding. I formatted it. Check its ok.

Comment: Not what you were asking about, but on click you might want to disable the button until all of the animations are complete, because multiple clicks will really confuse things...

Answer (score 1):

You have this under `complete:`

```
$(".box").each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(500);
});
```

I moved it to just before `$(this).delay(600 * i).animate [...]`

Now the blocks have delays between them.

Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/HdpPj/12/

Comment: Good luck with your animation. :)